# How can I find a specific word in an audio file?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, python, audio-processing

I'm trying to train and use a neural network to detect a specific word in an audio file. The input of the neural network is an audio of 2-3 seconds duration, and the neural network must determine whether the input audio (the voice of a person) contains the word "hello"  or not.

I do not know what kind of network to use. I used the SOM network, but I did not get the desired result. My training data contains a large number of voices that contain the word "hello".

Is there any python code for dis problem?

Comment: You can use a CNN or LSTM model. For the CNN one you can try pre-trained models for starting and for the LSTM one you can try bidirectional LSTMs.

Comment: What datasheet should I use to train the class related to "not hello"?

Comment: Have you tried looking at some models at tensorflow hub? I’m positive there should be some useful stuff

Answer (score 2):

After some research on the internet, I realized that using VOSK toolkit in python, it can be found (detect) any particular word in audio file or real time audio streaming.

https://alphacephei.com/vosk/